# Что такое Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, cookie, html5

В гугл хроме наткнулся на такую вещь как Local Storage. Она работает по типу куки (т.е. на стороне клиента сохраняется переменная и её значения).

Я занимаюсь разработкой online консультанта для сайта, так вот посмотрел, что большинство уже существующих online консультаций используют именно эту Local Storage. Почему именно Local Storage? Почему не cookie?

Comment: Я очень слабо представляю себе, что такое «online консультант» (к слову, прямо сейчас я вас консультирую онлайн) и какие объемы там необходимо хранить на клиенте, но отмечу, что в куках очень мало места для хранения (несколько тыс. символов).

Comment: Т.е. преимущество Local Storage в том, что больше места для хранения информации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отличие от cookie данные в LocalStorage всегда хранятся только на стороне клиента. Недостатки cookie:

- данные, хранимые в cookie, могут отслеживаться третьими лицами;
- многие обозреватели имеют ограничения на размер cookie в 4 кб;
- в cookie приходится хранить идентификатор сессии, чтобы извлекать емкие данные из базы;

Достоинства LocalStorage:

- просто использовать;
- существенно больше места - от 5-10 Мб на домен;
- данные в LocalStorage доступны из JavaScript;
- хранятся локально у клиента.

Comment: То есть куки по-вашему могут храниться не только на стороне клиента? =)

>В отличие от cookie данные в LocalStorage всегда хранятся только на стороне клиента.

Comment: куки очень часто имеют свойство переходить из "рук в руки", особенно из-за криворукости кодеров

Comment: Кроме достоинств, LocalStorage ещё не достаточно отлажен для кроссбраузерного использования. Это только в спецификации всё красиво. В реальности же - разработчики сталкиваются с некорректной работой хранилища. В хроме, например, есть возможность забить всё свободное место на диске C:\. В ИЕ есть проблемы синхронизации. И тд.

Answer (score 0):

> Local storage (локальное хранилище) — база данных на стороне клиента, содержащая пары ключ-значение.
>
> Особенности Local storage:
>
> - Большой объем хранилища (ограничивается только настройками браузера и свободным местом на жестком диске)
> - Данные хранятся на стороне клиента (высокая производительность)
> - Неограниченное время жизни
>
> Поддержка браузеров довольно хорошая:
>
> - IE 8+
> - Firefox 3.5+
> - Safari 4+
> - Chrome 4+
> - Opera 10.5+
> - iPhone 2+
> - Android 2+

Более подробно [у Саши Плютова в статье HTML5 Local Storage](http://plutov.by/post/html5_local_storage).